# Somehow "ctrl+w, = " doesnt' automatically adjust the window size in vimdiff since sometime ago

Tags: vim

On my ubuntu-20.04 machine while viewing two files with vimdiff, after I resize the terminal window, when I press 'ctrl-w' and '=' the divider line between the left and right windows of vimdiff re-adjusted to the resized terminal window to make them even in size. This worked for a long time. But recently, I found it doesn't work(I mean, the left/right windows size is not re-adjusted). I found if I press 'ctrl-Z' to come out to the shell and press 'fg', then it works again. I tried it in terminator window and normal terminal but it's same. Maybe I can reboot the computer but I don't want to do that for this. I can do away with it, but how can I make it work again(without pressing 'Z' and 'fg')?

Or Better yet, how can I use mouse to move the dividor line between the vimdiff windows? for example, this will be convenient when I compare 4 files at the same time.
**ADD:** I found I can do it with gvimdiff but I would be happy if can do it in normal terminal.